# How to hide ionic 3 splash screen for android device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I have tried the various techniques but unable to hide the splash screen on android device.

I am using ionic 3 and cordova 8.

This is what I have done to hide the splash screen.

1. In config.xml file I have added the following preferences

   [image]
2. In app.components.ts file I have added the following code in

initializeApp() {

```
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.statusBar.styleDefault();
        this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
```

}

Splash screen is being shown almost 10 seconds. But if I change the 

to

Splash icon is shown for 3 seconds and then rest of 8-10 seconds white screen is being appeared.

Please help me, how to hide splash screen.

Comment: Did you try `<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following preference to *config.xml*

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>
```

or just

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>
```